# Is there any option available in Azure Search for spell check?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I am using azure search in my bot application.

In this if we give input with spelling mistake, for small words like trvel => travel we are getting response properly.

But if i enter "travelexpense" for this i am not getting any result.
Currently i am passing input to do fuzzy search.

I have suggested to use Bing Spell Check API, but it is not approved as they think our input may be stored outside.

Is there any option available in azure search to correct the words like  "travelexpense".

Is there any option available for this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

The closest I would say is a phonetic Analyzer.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-add-custom-analyzers

There a couple of other things you can try:

- Enable Auto Complete and Suggestions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-autocomplete-tutorial)
- Create synonyms (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-synonyms)